# why i lost radio button created by simple form when submit an form with error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I have a form like this:

[image: new question]

When i submit form without any content, it shows errors:

[image: error new question]

The radio button is lost !

This is in my form view:

```
<%= simple_form_for @question, defaults: { error: false } do |q| %>

  <legend>Question</legend>
  <%= render "shared/error_messages", object: q.object %>

  <%= q.input :content, input_html: { rows: 3, class: 'span6' } %>
  <%= q.input :mark, input_html: { class: 'span1' } %>
  <%= q.association :topic %>
  <%= q.association :question_type %>

  <%= q.simple_fields_for :answers do |a| %>
    <%= a.input :correct, collection: [[true, 'True'], [false, 'False']],
                                                            as: :radio_buttons,
                                                            label: 'Answer',
                                                            value_method: :first,
                                                            label_method: :last,
                                                            item_wrapper_class: 'inline'
                                                            %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

What's i missed or wrong? I used `render 'new'` in my create action of Question controller when @question.save is false. This is my question controller:

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @question = Question.new
    @question.answers.build
  end

  def create
    @question = Question.new(content: params[:question][:content])
    @question.mark = params[:question][:mark]
    @question.topic_id = params[:question][:topic_id]
    @question.question_type_id = params[:question][:question_type_id]
    @question.user_id = current_user.id

    if @question.save
      if params[:question][:answers_attributes]['0'][:correct] == 'true'
        answer = @question.answers.build(content: 'True')
        answer.correct = true
      else
        answer = @question.answers.build(content: 'False')
      end
      if @question.save
        flash[:success] = "Successfully created new question."
        redirect_to root_url
      else
        render 'new'
      end
    else
      render 'new'
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added @question.answers.build above last render 'new' and it works now

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're building a new `answer` with the `build_answer` method (or an other way) on your `@question` object in your controller, probably in the `new` method.

What happens is that when the `create` action fails then the `@question` has no `answers`, and the `simple_fields_for` won't display anything.

if you need more details, please post the code of your controller and we'll try to find out how to solve the problem.

EDIT : The way you're building your Question is wrong, it should be

```
@question = Question.new(params[:question])
```

then your `@question` will have an answer, and everything will work fine in your view ;)

Comment: I got it. In rails doc [Using render](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render), "Rails does not run any of the code for that action in the controller", so i added @question.answers.build above last render 'new' and it works now.

Comment: No, the way i build my question is right ;), because only content in attr_accessible. Anyway thanks for your answer, i voted it ;)

Comment: I really don't think it's correct, because your way is adding a lot of code, for instance the whole thing you're doing with the nested_attributes could be done automatically with the solution I posted and of course by adding answer_attributes in the attr_accessible list. I don't see any advantage of keeping only the content in the attr_accessible list

Comment: yes, but if i do mass-assignment, it will have problem with security, because someone can change answer, or the correct attribute type boolean of answer.

Comment: How do you think that someone can change those things ?

Comment: You can read about [Mass Assignment Security](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18680/discussion-between-pjam-and-thanh-huynh)